# I want to ask for notification permission in flutter for IOS, But it is showing PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied. What should I do?

Tags: flutter

```
void checkPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.status;
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.request();
      // print('permission Request');
      print("djdhwdfc");
      print(status);
    } else {
      print('permission is granted');
    }
  }
```

I tried lots of videos to get a solution but didn't find a solution.

Output:

```
djdhwdfc
PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied
```

Comment: you'll need to prompt the user to manually enable the notification permission for your app in the ios device settings. you can do this by displaying a dialog and provides a button that takes the user to the app's settings page

Comment: I did this, but in the settings it was showing that the permission is given but in the console it was printing PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied